# How to Convert from C# to Java JDBC

Tags: c#, java, mysql, jdbc

I have this code using C# to manipulate data in SQL Server:

```
using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
{
    myDatabaseConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Users where Username = @UserName and Password = @Password", myDatabaseConnection))
    {
        SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBox1.Text);
        SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text);
        SqlDataReader DR1 = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (DR1.Read())
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

How would I translate it to Java using JDBC and MySQL as the database? And can I avoid SQL injection?

My attempt:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password)) {
    String sql = "Select * from Users where Username = @UserName and Password = @Password";
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    //parameters?
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    while (result.next()) {
        //some code
    }        
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC uses `?` characters as placeholders where bind variables would normally go.  You must use a `PreparedStatement` to use `?` placeholders.  Then you can call `setXXX` methods (1-based indexes here!) to bind the variables and then execute.

```
String sql = "Select * from Users where Username = ? and Password = ?";
PreparedStatement pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pStatement.setString(1, username);
pStatement.setString(2, password);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Does DataReader.Read() is equivalent of result.next() ?

Comment: From what I can tell online about `SqlDataReader`'s `Read()` (I'm not a C# person), it appears to be equivalent to `ResultSet`'s `next()` method.  It advances to the next record and returns a `boolean` if there is a next record.